# Parent Page > Child Page Menu

Tags: menus, child-pages, pages

I am trying to create a collapsible menu using Bootstrap. The problem I am having is getting the correct Wordpress PHP code to call the right pages. Also this menu will be displayed on these child pages.

I would like the menu hierarchy to look like this:

Specific Page 1
--- Child Page One
--- Child Page Two

Specific Page 2
--- Child Page One
--- Child Page Two

Comment: This part of the question isn't clear: `The problem I am having is getting the correct Wordpress PHP code to call the right pages`. Also, are you using a custom theme or a contributed theme based on Bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry let me try and clarify. I am using a custom bootstrap theme. I was trying to implement wp_list_pages, but I can't seem to get the right "arguements" I guess you would say. Looking at this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Why don't you create a menu from WordPress? That should handle the hierarchy automatically and you would just need to override the classes to use Bootstrap styling.

Comment: That was my first thought. I have done so successfully with other menu's but this menu in particular is for the mobile version. I can't seem to figure out how to implement a stacked COLLAPSIBLE menu using WP's menu system. I do already have some bootstrap styled stacked menu items, but I need this version to be collapsible like the attached image. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73982197/nav.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new navigation walker class in your theme, in which you will override the default output to match the one required by Bootstrap.

Download a drop-in nav walker class for Bootstrap [here](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) and do the following:

1. Load the new walker class in your theme's `template.php` file:

   require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
2. Create the menu in admin.
3. Use the following code to display it:

   ```
   <?php
       wp_nav_menu( array(
           'menu'              => 'primary',
           'theme_location'    => 'primary',
           'depth'             => 2,
           'container'         => 'div',
           'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
           'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
           'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
           'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
       );
   ?>
   ```

Check out also [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme/) which explains how to do this using the same existing class for Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi that is quite helpful. I already have nav walker installed, version 2.0.2. When I insert the code above, the links give a dropdown arrow/menu. I need the collapse feature.

Comment: Also, the menu would not show up unless I enter false, for 'container'

Comment: The collapse feature should be there automatically - all dropdowns turn into collapsibles on small screens. What exactly do you mean by `I need the collapse feature`?

Comment: Hm, odd. In that case my dropdowns are not automatically turning into collapsibles. UPDATE: OKAY NM,  that seems to be working. Is there anyway to get the collapse feature to work with the nav-stacked option instead of using the navbar?

Comment: Check the browser's console log for any JS errors. You can see what I'm talking about if you resize the screen on [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/) example layout.

Comment: Please see updated comment

Comment: I'm guessing that you would have to edit the JS files that provide togglable effects. It would be easier to override `navbar` styles on that particular menu, rather than overriding the JS.

Comment: okay, perhaps setting up separate navbar styles will do the trick. Thank you!